# Python automatically find server with ZMQ

Tags: python, server, client, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using ZMQ to facilitate communications between one server and multiple clients. Is there a method to have the clients automatically find the ZMQ server if they are on the same internal network? My goal would be to have the client be able to automatically detect the IP and Port it should connect to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in any sort of scalable way without *some* sort of broker or manager that will manage your communications system.

The way that would work is that you have your broker on a known IP:port, and as your server and clients spin up, they connect to the broker, and the broker then tells your endpoints how to communicate to each other.

There are some circumstances where such a communication pattern could make sense, generally when the server and clients are controlled by different entities, and maybe even different from the entity controlling the broker.  In your case, it sounds like a dramatic amount of over-engineering.  The only other way to do what you're looking for that I'm aware of is to just start brute forcing the network to find open IP:port combinations that respond the way you are looking for.  Ick.

I suggest you just define the IP:port you want to use, probably through some method of static configuration you can change manually as necessary, or that can act as sort of a flat-file broker that both ends of the communication can access.